# Dev c++ no da el resultado correcto

Tags: c, dev-c++

Tardes o Noches tengo un problema al hacer este problema en Dev c++ que cuando ejecuto el programa me arroja un resultado ilogico y no se a que se debe este error agradecería una respuesta de su parte.
Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en la línea número 19, no le estás pasando qué variables quiere que muestre con el `%i`.

Es decir, si tú tienes que mostarar cuánto vale n, lo que haces es: `printf("%i", n)`, acuérdate siempre de pasar la variable, porque sino mostrará cualquier cosa.

Este sería tu código arreglado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i,n,in;
    printf(" Ingrese n: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    i=0;
    in=1;
    while(i<n){ // no es menor igual a n, porque sino mostrara n+1 numeros pares
        if(in%2==0){
            printf(" %i.\n",in); // paso in porque in es par
            i++;
        }
        in++;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

La ejecución con n=2, te dará:

> Ingrese n: 2
>
> 2.
>
> 4.

**Aclaración:**

No te arreglé el `in=1;` porque supuse que estás trabajando con números pares naturales, no enteros positivos o iguales a 0.

Comment: Agradecido por tu ayuda @Zeugirdor